# How to Parse XML data from web service?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xml-parsing

I am successful to load XML from the App_Data Folder with this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Data;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using XMLTest2.Models;

namespace XMLTest2.Controllers
{
    public class PeopleController : ApiController
    {
        public List<XMLpeople> GetAllPeople()
        {
            var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/XML_Test.xml");
            List<XMLpeople> people = new List<XMLpeople>();
            XMLpeople NewPerson = new XMLpeople();
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);

            foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("people").Descendants("person"))
            {
                NewPerson.id = element.Element("id").Value;
                NewPerson.name = element.Element("name").Value;
                NewPerson.age = element.Element("age").Value;
                NewPerson.description = element.Element("description").Value;
                people.Add(NewPerson);
            }

            return people;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I Wish to Create a Restful Service from this to a client. I am trying to parse this for days with these code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;

namespace XMLTest2.Models
{
    public class PeopleRestService
    {
        public List<XMLpeople> GetAllPeople()
        {
            string current_hostname = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
            string api_url = "api/people";
            string url = current_hostname + api_url;

            WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
            using (var stream = proxy.OpenRead(url))
            {
                var response = proxy.DownloadString(url);
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(response); //I Got an error here. It says. Illegal characters in path.
                DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
                datatable.ReadXml(reader);

                List<XMLpeople> xxx = new List<XMLpeople>();

                xxx = (from DataRow row in datatable.Rows
                       select new XMLpeople
                       {
                           id = row["id"].ToString(),
                           name = row["name"].ToString(),
                           age = row["age"].ToString(),
                           description = row["description"].ToString()
                       }).ToList();
                return xxx;
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Any Help or Links would be much apprecitaed Thanks!, and for the record i'm new to Asp.net MVC web api.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the response that throws an error when passed to `XmlReader.Create`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry Sir. I Can't I Wish could just show an image so you can see it. stackOverflow says i can't add that image and i need 10 more reputation to be able to do that.

Comment: Good. Because *we don't want an image* - post correctly formatted text :)

Comment: Put a break point on that line of code then copy the string value out.  If it is huge put in on pastebin and just provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [`XmlReader.Create(string)` *does not* take in an XML string!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k674bf.aspx) It takes in a URI - passing a string containing XML will most definitely lead to an Exception!

Instead, use `XmlReader.Create(Stream)` or [`XmlReader.Create(TextReader)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z042k543%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). In this case it's pretty easy to use a [StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) (which is a sub-type of `TextReader`) to load the data:

```
var response = proxy.DownloadString(url);
using (var sr = new StringReader(response)) {
  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);
  // ..
}
```

It is probably also possible to use `stream` directly - i.e. `XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream)` - and skip `DownloadString` entirely although their *might* be some encoding differences.

Comment: thank you for your patience! i've tried your example and i got this new error, that says. 

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: @Mark What are the contents of the string? Is is [valid] XML?

Comment: do you mean the contents of the XML file that I created for testing?

Comment: @Mark Whatever the web service returned - it might have returned something unexpected! Attach a debugger, break on Exceptions, and then take a peek at the values of the variables.

Comment: if you meant the content of the variable response. sorry again sir!, please bear with me. really a newbie here.

response "[{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"\\n      edison reyes\\n    \",\"age\":\"\\n      23\\n    \",\"description\":\"\\n      hello world 2\\n    \"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"\\n      edison reyes\\n    \",\"age\":\"\\n      23\\n    \",\"description\":\"\\n      hello world 2\\n    \"}]" string

Comment: That's not XML - it's JSON. Trying to read it as XML just won't work.

Comment: That looks like JSON with character escaping. Use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();` and then `JSS.Deserialize();`

Comment: @user2864740 i'm sorry if you meant from what the web service displays. it's 
<br/>
    '<ArrayOfXMLpeople xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <XMLpeople>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>edison reyes</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <description>hello world 2</description>
    </XMLpeople>
    <XMLpeople>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>edison reyes</name>
    <age>23</age>
    <description>hello world 2</description>
    </XMLpeople>
    </ArrayOfXMLpeople>'

Comment: @Mark I only care about *what is in* the `response` variable. It apparently *is not valid XML*, per the Exception message. Attach the debugger to inspect what the *actual* downloaded string is and work from there.

Comment: @Mark Also, I believe the DownloadString doesn't honor BOM markings (and these may appears as "junk" at the start of the string), so if the string in `response` otherwise *looks* like XML - which the first data posted in a comment surely wasn't! - then that should be checked too.